# create a linux binary (executable) that contains const data only

Tags: linux, scripting, binary, executable

On Linux using any computer script/language, is there a way to create/generate a binary (executable), which it ONLY has const data without any functions/main()? for example, We have the following structure (in C format) and the binary will only has the following const data:

```
const struct {
    uint32_t mag;
    uint16_t ver;
    uint16_t par_no;
    uint32_t level;
} foo = {1, 2, 3, 0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easily:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdint.h>
const struct {
    uint32_t mag;
    uint16_t ver;
    uint16_t par_no;
    uint32_t level;
} foo = {1, 2, 3, 0};

$ gcc foo.c -c -o foo.o

$ ld foo.o -o foo
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000
```

(the warning is not fatal).

The resulting executable has a 12 byte `.rodata` segment and no `.text` segment.